# Google Webmaster tool to Adobe analytics

Tags: adobe-analytics

I am wondering if it is possible to connect GWT account to Adobe Analytics? I could not find any documentation on this. please let me know
Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to import GWT data to AA?

Comment: yes. Is this possible?

Comment: yes - but depends on data dimensions,metrics and any other data you wanted tied to it (search terms, campaigns, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If you get GWT data exported then yes you can import that in Adobe Analytics using Data Sources.